# Who is the most powerful mage in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was wondering what's the strongest mage NPC in Skyrim. Like what one has the most spells or the master level spells? Who is the best? Is it the arch mage?

Comment: From lore perspective or actual game play? The Arch mage gets killed as part of the mage guild story, but otherwise they'll all essential characters and can't die.

Comment: Regarding power, chain lightning / lightning bolt users will be the best because the magic comes out instant. Ice based are the worst, especially ice storm, since it is super slow.

Comment: Do undead count?

Comment: I was thinking in game potential and lightning does seem most powerful and yes undead included

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you count shouts as magic, objectively speaking Miraak would be the strongest "Mage" as he knows:

1. Fire Breath
2. Frost Breath
3. Bend Will
4. Dragon Aspect
5. Become Ethereal
6. Cyclone
7. Whirlwind Sprint
8. Unrelenting Force

Also his level is the player level times 1.1 (up to 150) so he'll always be stronger than you until you reach 151, which most other characters can't reach.

After that it would be the Solstheim Dragon Priests (Capped at level 60) who use actual spells. All other "mages" are significally weaker.

Comment: +1 But up to player levels 25 and 50 the answer might vary slightly :)

Comment: @Joachim these would still be more powerful due to their minimum levels.

Comment: At some point J'zargo might be considered best mage since he doesn't have level cap if you made him follower(IIRC). Might be wrong though, haven't played Skyrim for years

Comment: Levels don't affect spell damage.

Comment: @Nelson it does make them stronger.